# Read file /proc/{pid}/comm in c linux

Tags: c, linux, proc, ps

I want read file /proc/{PID}/comm (the name of the proccess) and write near PID in my simple ps command

```
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    const char l[]="0123456789";

    if ((dir = opendir("/proc")) == NULL)
        perror("operation error");
    else 
    {
        printf(" PID      CMD\n");

        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)

            if(strspn(ent->d_name, l)) 
            {
                printf(" %s\n", ent->d_name);
            }

        closedir(dir);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I readed lot of examples, but i don;t have idea how should it looks like in my code.

Have somebody any ideas

Comment: There's nothing special about reading this file, just read it like any other file.

Comment: @FelixPalmen whenever i try my main loop break after writing 1 pid

Comment: and how can i place variable in path to open it? @FelixPalmen

Comment: Try `sprintf()` / `snprintf()` to construct the path for `fopen()`.